# Nokia N73 unable to connect to laptop

Tags: internet, phone

I am connecting my Nokia N73 through data cable with my laptop which has Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

If I connect using Windows, it gets connected and I can browse all the files and folders in my phone from the computer. If I connect from Ubuntu then its not getting connected, so and I am unable browse the internet or files on my phone.

Any support would be great help for me.

Comment: Please paste output of `dmesg` and `lsusb`.

(Open terminal and copy past output of the commands).

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access the files, go to `Settings > Connectivity > USB Data Cable` on your phone and in `USB Data Cable` either set `Ask on conn.` or `Data Storage`. The PC will then detect your phone as a normal USB drive and you can easily access contents.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Software Centre I found [Wammu](http://wammu.eu/) and [GMobileMedia](http://gmobilebrowser.sourceforge.net/). I have no experience with them but they may allow you to use your phone as you want. see below screens

[image: Wammu]

[image: GMobileMedia]